# Installing development tools in RHEL 6

Tags: yum, rhel-6

I have admin privilege on my office computer (running RHEL 6) which is connected in a network. I was trying to install development tools using the command: `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`  but I got an error message saying:

```
Updating certificate-based repositories.
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.

Error Message:
 Please run rhn_register as root on this client
 Error Class Code: 9
 Error Class Info: Invalid System Credentials.
```

I tried to run rhn_register, it said `"It appears this system has already been registered for software updates"`.

What is the problem actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install new updates with yum you need to register your system with RHN(Red Hat Network) which is a paid service.

Pay attention to these error lines:

```
There was an error communicating with RHN.
Error Class Info: Invalid System Credentials.
```

Since it says that your system was previously registered (depending on how your system was deployed) it might have preserved the reg file `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/systemid`, you can remove it and try `rhn_register`. You will be challenged for username and password when registering a system with RHN.
If this still doesn't work than you have bigger issues related to networking.

Ref: [rhn](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.3/html/Reference_Guide/ch-register.html)

Comment: When I followed your instruction and tried to register my computer on RHN afresh, it said something like all channels have been exhausted.

Comment: it means you are out of entitlements. you can reuse them or get pay for more.

Comment: *Adding to Dejan's Answer:*
You open a new case at [Red Hat Customer Portal][1] and post your issue there. You should get better help in your case.


  [1]: https://access.redhat.com/home